# Failing to simulate data for a negative binomial probability distribution

Tags: r, linear-regression, simulation, bayesian

I am hoping someone can help me.

In a beginners workshop I attended, in the process of fitting a multiple regression model, the instructor initially established a prior predictive check using a Poisson distribution for the outcome. This was done in two steps. Initially, a function was created:

```r
    multiple_regression_poisson_dgp <- function(predictor1, 
          predictor2, alpha_mean, alpha_sd, beta_predictor1_mean, 
          beta_predictor1_sd,  beta_predictor2_mean, 
          beta_predictor2_sd) {
    N <- length(predictor1)
    alpha <- rnorm(1, mean = alpha_mean, sd = alpha_sd);
    beta_predictor1 <- rnorm(1, mean = beta_predictor1_mean, 
            sd = beta_predictor1_sd);
    beta_predictor2 <- rnorm(1, mean = beta_predictor2_mean, 
            sd = beta_super_sd);
    outcome <- rpois(N, lambda = alpha + beta_predictor1 * 
                predictor1 + beta_predictor2 * predictor2)
    return(outcome)
    }
```

After this function was created, the following priors were generated:

```r
    multiple_regression_poisson_dgp(dataset$predictor1,
                                dataset$predictor2,
                                alpha_mean = 1,
                                alpha_sd = 0.5,
                                beta_predictor1_mean = -0.25,
                                beta_predictor1_sd = 0.5,
                                beta_predictor2_mean = 0,
                                beta_predictor2_sd = 1)
```

This worked fine. The issue is that, further down the line, it was shown that the Poisson distribution was not the most adequate. The negative binomial was suggested as the next step. Unfortunately, when I try to replicate the process for the negative binomial, I am unsuccessful. I have tried to replicate both of the steps shown above, but for the negative binomial. The first step was coded as:

```r
    multiple_regression_negative_binomial_dgp <- 
       function(predictor1, predictor2, alpha_mean, alpha_sd, 
       beta_predictor1_mean, beta_predictor1_sd, 
       beta_predictor2_mean, beta_predictor2_sd, phi_mean, 
       phi_sd) {
    N <- length(predictor1)
    alpha <- rnorm(1, mean = alpha_mean, sd = alpha_sd);
    beta_predictor1 <- rnorm(1, mean = beta_predictor1_mean, 
        sd = beta_predictor1_sd); 
    beta_predictor2 <- rnorm(1, mean = beta_predictor2_mean, 
        sd = beta_super_sd);
    phi <- rnorm(1, mean = phi_mean, sd = phi_sd);
    outcome<- rnbinom(N, size = mu + mu^2/phi, mu = alpha + 
          beta_predictor1 * predictor1 + beta_predictor2 * 
               predictor2)
    return(outcome)
    }
```

Because there is a phi in the negative binomial, and given that it will be a parameter whose prior I will be calculating, I assumed it needed to be added to the equation. Additionally, given the documentation for `rnbinom()`, I thought i could treat mu as I treated lambda in the Poisson generation, feeding the regression equation onto it.

The function is likely inadequate, but after I create it and move onto the second step, the errors emerge. The second step I coded as:

```r
    multiple_regression_negative_binomial_dgp(dataset$predictor1,
                                dataset$predictor2,
                                alpha_mean = 1,
                                alpha_sd = 0.5,
                                beta_predictor1_mean = -0.25,
                                beta_predictor1_sd = 0.5,
                                beta_predictor2_mean = 0,
                                beta_predictor2_sd = 1,
                                phi_mean = 0,
                                phi_sd = 1)
```

However, as soon as I try to run this data generating process, I get the warning stating:

```r
    Error in rnbinom(N, size = mu, mu = alpha + beta_predictor1 * predictor1 + beta_predictor2 * predictor2 : object 'mu' not found
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I realize that I am applying a more mechanistic mindset in trying to replicate the Poisson data generating process for the negative binomial one, but I have been unable to find any clues as to how to solve this. Most examples I came across define a value for mu and for size, instead of 'feeding' it the formula.

Comment: What is the `size = mu + mu^2/phi` in your `rnbinom` call in your 2nd function?  I don't see `mu` passed to the function or defined within it. Also, `mu` is the name of the next argument for `rnbinom`, which makes it seem like it might be overloaded.

Comment: Hi @gung - Reinstate Monica, thank you. In the rnbinom() documentation it is stated that "An alternative parametrization (often used in ecology) is by the mean mu, and size, the dispersion parameter, where prob = size/(size+mu). The variance is mu + mu^2/size in this parametrization." Given feedback received at the workshop, my interpretation was that i would have to use this format in the data generation process. As for the mu, in the function I have "mu = alpha + beta_predictor1 * predictor1 + beta_predictor2 * predictor2". Is that not passing it to the function?

Comment: No, that's not the way R works. You don't pass one argument to another, unless the function was designed to do that. I'll make this an answer. This Q should probably be migrated to [SO].

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will keep trying to figure out what I should have done instead.

Comment: You're welcome, @Stats Illiterate. +1 for a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `multiple_regression_negative_binomial_dgp` function, you call `rnbinom`.  That function needs a `size` argument, and you assign `mu + mu^2/phi` to it, but `mu` is not defined within the function, nor passed to it.  The fact that `rnbinom` contains a `mu` argument, which you do provide (`alpha + beta_predictor1 * predictor1 + beta_predictor2 * predictor2`), doesn't take care of it, because `rnbinom` doesn't pass that information over to `size`.  I would suggest you try:

```
multiple_regression_negative_binomial_dgp <- function(predictor1, predictor2,  
                                alpha_mean, alpha_sd, beta_predictor1_mean, 
                                beta_predictor1_sd, beta_predictor2_mean, 
                                beta_predictor2_sd, phi_mean,  phi_sd) {
  N               <- length(predictor1)
  alpha           <- rnorm(1, mean=alpha_mean,           sd=alpha_sd)
  beta_predictor1 <- rnorm(1, mean=beta_predictor1_mean, sd=beta_predictor1_sd) 
  beta_predictor2 <- rnorm(1, mean=beta_predictor2_mean, sd=beta_super_sd);
  phi             <- rnorm(1, mean=phi_mean,             sd=phi_sd)
  Mu              <- alpha + beta_predictor1*predictor1 + beta_predictor2*predictor2
  outcome         <- rnbinom(N, size=Mu + Mu^2/phi, mu=Mu)
  return(outcome)
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. It worked. Cannot tell you how great this is, I had been looking at this for a while now without any answers and, all of the sudden, you really helped me out. I imagine this happens quite often but just want to emphasise how much I appreciate your help and the time you took out of your day to help someone you do not know! All the best!